# Re-appended Canvas element keeps content

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

Parser is a modul that is able to draw xml on the target canvas. After removing the original canvas element and appending the clean canvas, the canvas resets, but after further re-appendings the content of the canvas remains the same.

```js
function setAttributes(elem, attrs) {
  for (var key in attrs) {
    elem.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}

var Parser = (function() {
  var cleanCanvas = (function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    setAttributes(canvas, {
      "id": "canvas",
      "style": "border: 2px solid black",
      "width": "200px",
      "height": "200px"
    });
    return canvas;
  })();

  return {
    parseSVG: function(data, target) {
      lastTarget = $("#" + target).clone();
      var canvas = document.getElementById(target);
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

      var img = new Image();
      var svg = new Blob([data], {
        type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
      });
      var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }

      img.src = url;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

      var img = new Image();
      var svg = new Blob([data], {
        type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
      });
      var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }

      img.src = url;
    },

    clearCanvas: function() {
      document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("canvas"));
      document.body.appendChild(cleanCanvas);
    }
  }
})();

//Tried in console:

var data =
  '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
  '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
  '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
  '<h1>blah</h1>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</foreignObject>' +
  '</svg>';

//Works properly
Parser.parseSVG(data, "canvas");
Parser.clearCanvas();

//Doesn't work properly
Parser.parseSVG(data, "canvas");
Parser.clearCanvas();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 2px solid black" width="200px" height="200px">
  </canvas>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="html2img.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Why the content stays the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cleanCanvas` is the same reference in everywhere, with same context. This means:

```
// after appending cleanCanvas to body

alert(cleanCanvas === document.getElementById('canvas'));

/* --> true */
```

You could make `cleanCanvas` a function instead, so you can re-generate it by calling it.

```
var getCleanCanvas = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    canvas.id = 'canvas';
    canvas.style.border = '2px solid black';

    setAttributes(canvas, {
        "width": "200px",
        "height": "200px"
    });

    return canvas;
};
```

Now:

```
document.body.appendChild(getCleanCanvas());
```

Comment: Alright. This works fine, but the attributes were not proper the way you've defined, but setting them with setAttribute is okay. So my cleanCanvas isn't a function, it is just has the return value of the anonymus function evaluated, am I right? That could cause my confusion.

Comment: @toboR_rM Exactly, but the attributes shouldn't be defined in this way, some old browsers doesn't handle them sometimes, they must be defined with default setters like `id`, `width`, etc... in `HTMLElement()`. Canvas works in modern browsers, though.